# Bluetooth stopped working

Tags: bluetooth

after some upgrade bluetooth stopped working.
Tried few guides how to troubleshoot, but couldn't find anything usefull.

`Bluetooth service is not running well:
Bal 14 22:42:13  bluetoothd[961]: Not enough free handles to register service
Bal 14 22:42:13  bluetoothd[961]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Bal 14 22:42:13  bluetoothd[961]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Bal 14 22:42:30  bluetoothd[961]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndp
Bal 14 22:42:30  bluetoothd[961]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndp
Bal 14 22:42:40 A bluetoothd[961]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndp
Bal 14 22:42:40 A bluetoothd[961]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndp
Bal 14 22:42:40  bluetoothd[961]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: r
Bal 14 22:42:53  bluetoothd[961]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEn
Bal 14 22:42:53 bluetoothd[961]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEn`
Anyone can help on how to re-install bluetooth? or get back it online properly?

Alex

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1490349

Comment: That means I should upgrade to 16.10 Ubuntu?

Comment: It means it's a reported bug and as such off-topic. You may want to add yourself to the above bug report.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add? Just reply into the topic there?

Comment: Login with your Launchpad / Ubuntu SSO account and then click in the link "This bug affects ... people. Does this bug affect you?".

Comment: Thank you! so basically I need to wait for some sort of update? I mean can you please in short give me a brief on how it works with ubuntu?

Comment: Bugs are reported then they may or may not be solved. Feel free to test some of the workarounds scattered in the comments section.